# Trying to Resolve Shift Reduce Conflicts by Changing Grammar

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, lalr

Given the following specification for a grammar:

```
Statement → { Statement* }
      → VarDecl
      → if ( Exp ) Statement else Statement
      → while ( Exp ) Statement
      → System.out.println ( Exp ) ;
      → id = Exp ;
      → id [ Exp ]= Exp ;
```

These are the rules I've come up with to use in a YACC/BISON program. I have Shift/Reduce Conflicts though.

```
StatementList:
    '{' StatementList Statement '}'
     |  Statement
     ;

Statement: 
    |   VarDecl
    |   IF '('Exp')' StatementList ELSE StatementList
    |   WHILE'('Exp')' StatementList
    |   SOP'('Exp')' ';'
    |   ID '=' Exp ';'
    |   ID'['Exp']' '=' Exp';'
    ;
```

Also tried this grammar:

```
CompoundStatement:
        '{' StatementList '}'

StatementList:
    StatementList Statement
    |   Statement
    ;

Statement: 
    |   VarDecl
    |   IF '('Exp')' Statement ELSE Statement
    |   WHILE'('Exp')' Statement
    |   SOP'('Exp')' ';'
    |   ID '=' Exp ';'
    |   ID'['Exp']' '=' Exp';'
    |   CompoundStatement
    ;
```

Did not work either. Still had conflicts. (Though this passed the testcases I'd set up)

And neither did this:

```
StatementList
     : %empty /* Explicit empty production, bison 3.0+ */
     | StatementList Statement

Statement
     : '{' StatementList '}'
     | IF '('Exp')' Statement ELSE Statement
     | /* ... and the rest of the statements */
```

Any help?

Comment: My solution is conflict-free when I try it. Did you remember to change `StatementList` to `Statement` in the `WHILE` statement? Otherwise, there is something going on in the declaration of VarDecl or Exp, which are not shown in your question.

Comment: Oh, and your second attempt also has an empty production for Statement. That's ambiguous in a StatementList because you don't know how many empty Statements an empty StatementList comprises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have an empty production for `Statement`. You probably didn't intend to; you certainly don't need to; and it is probably the cause of your conflicts.
2. Your production for blocks is wrong. You need to define `StatementList` in order to implement `Statement*`, and then follow through with your original grammar:

   ```
   StatementList
        : %empty /* Explicit empty production, bison 3.0+ */
        | StatementList Statement

   Statement
        : '{' StatementList '}'
        | IF '('Exp')' Statement ELSE Statement
        | /* ... and the rest of the statements */
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question to include the other grammar I tried (which failed as well)

Comment: Also, I don't have an empty production in Statement. A semicolon just marks end of the block. To have an empty production, I would write `code` Statement : /*List of Statements */ | ;

Comment: @user2116243: That's precisely what you wrote. The newline after the colon is just whitespace.

Comment: I'm an idiot. That was it. What a damn waste of three hours of my life :P

Comment: I hadn't noticed the | ahead of VarDecl. You are precious rici :D